# Minecraft Already Running Error

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Whenever I try to play Minecraft, it pops up with an error saying "Game Already Running" I've tried restarting my computer, and looking online for fixes. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Nvm I Fixed the problem

Comment: Then write an answer instead of just saying that!

Comment: Can you add the answer then? It would help other people having the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

Since we aren't getting an answer from Currupt_Bat I will provide the solution whenever I had similar problems:

Open your Task-Manager (Ctrl+Alt+Del) and look for the process "minecraft" and manually shut it down. 
Problems like these usually appear if you have not enough patience and start the application multiple times, by clicking it's icon multiple times.

Comment: Also look for java.exe and javaw.exe, those are the processes of the Java "System" that Minecraft uses.